# Tracing and fixing memory leaks ios

Tags: ios, xcode

How do we trace and fix the memory leaks in ios/xcode?
If someone can mention the steps it would be beneficial for all.

Comment: http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/identify-memory-leaks-during-ios-app-development-using-instruments-with-xcode/

Comment: Step 2: Search Google: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=detect%20memory%20leaks%20ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for prevention: use [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
2. for cure: use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp.html)